# React Native - @emotion/native - TextInput placeholder text color attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, styled-components, emotion

I am trying to pass the `placeholderTextColor` attribute through the `styled.TextInput.attrs` function. The reason why I'm doing this is so I can access the theme `props`.

This is what I have:

```
const TextInput = styled.TextInput.attrs(props => ({
  placeholderTextColor: "red",
  type: "password"
}))`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.text};
`
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
_native.default.TextInput.attrs is not a function. (In '_native.default.TextInput.attrs(function (props) {
    return {
      placeholderTextColor: "red",
      type: "password"
    };
  })', '_native.default.TextInput.attrs' is undefined)
```

Comment: How did you import your 'styled' ?

Comment: @AshwinMothilal like so: `import styled from "@emotion/native"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `@emotion/native` does not support the `attrs` function yet, so I moved over to `styled-components`.